# Integer field type missing

Tags: entities

I am using Drupal 7.12 and are missing the field type "integer". I only have the fields

```
Boolean
List (Text) 
List (Float)
LIst (Integer)
Long Text
Long Text and Summary
Node Reference
Text
```

Maybe I am overseeing here something very basic, but it should be there AFAIK.

Thx for help,

n3rd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check and see if the core module "Number" is enabled. It requires the Field and Field SQL storage modules to be enabled as well.

Comment: Indeed it is not enabled, here we go.